# Atomで囲んだ選択している文字だけをコメントアウトする方法はありますか？

Tags: atom-editor

Atomで囲んだ（行単位でなく）選択している文字だけをコメントアウトする方法（ショートカットキー）はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

block-commentパッケージをインストールすると <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> でできるようです。
同様の機能を持ったパッケージは数種類あるようですので、いろいろお試しください。

Answer (score 1):

Macの場合コマンド+Shift+範囲選択で複数選択が可能です。そのあとコマンド+スラッシュでコメントアウトができます。